# python UDP socket client recevfrom is very slow

Tags: python, sockets, socket.io, udp, raspberry-pi3

Im using python3 code on a respberrypi 3.
this is the code on the server:

```
import json, time, requests, signal, sys, socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
sock.bind((s.settings["udpIP"], s.settings["udpPort"]))
sessions = {}
c = 0

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(65535)

if somedata is x:
        sequence = <clientSessionSeq> #startint at 000 and then 001 ( to monitor the udp packet so i wont lose any packets)
        sock.sendto(sequence, (addr))       # returning the client the seq i got so it may proceed sending the next one, if its not the same seq client will resend lost package
            s.print_info(
                {
                    "REMOTE_ADDRESS": addr,
                    "STATUS": "PUBLISH",
                },
            )         
            c = 0
        c = c + 1
```

Client code -

```
data = data_iter()
while True:
        # if seq is ok then pull next data
        dataTmp = next(data)
    sock.sendto(
        "ID ".encode() + headers["SESSION_ID"].encode() + sequence + dataTmp,
        (s.settings["server"]["ip"], s.settings["udpPort"]),
    )
    try:
        sock.settimeout(3)
        response, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    except IOError as  e:
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        traceback.print_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
        s.print_info(e)
```

My issue is in the client code at  `response, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)`  i sometimes get the timeout after the 3 seconds , server sending client the seq it received, but client recvfrom is stuck \ delayed.

is there a way to do some tuning to udp in the raspberrypi or the socket code ?

### i cant use tcp, i know it will work better, i have to work udp

If ill remove the `recivefrom` it runs good but i have packets lost, i use this for streaming recordings so i have to get full recording. i just need suggestions for tuning or maybe another way to use udp and not socket?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably this isn't caused by UDP being "very slow" and is actually just an example of packet loss.  Given that you say you need to work in UDP you need to handle this yourself.

I'd assume you're going to have to end up writing very similar code to what exists in TCP so I'd suggest looking there for how it's been solved before.  TCP uses something called sliding windows to track the state of packets that are "inflight" at any time, and there should be lots of existing documents written about how/why they work.